# Recursive Merge Sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, recursion, merge, stack-overflow

I'm attempting to write a recursive merge sort method for class. I keep getting stackoverflows when I attempt to `mergeSort(leftArr)` and `mergeSort(rightArr)`. Why doesn't the base case I have work?

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class SortingAlgorithms {
    public static void mergeSort(int[] list){

        int mid = list.length / 2;
        int [] leftArr = new int [mid];
        int [] rightArr;


        if (mid % 2 == 0) {
            rightArr = new int [mid];
        }
        else{
            rightArr = new int [mid + 1];
        }

        if (leftArr.length < 2 && rightArr.length < 2){
            list = mergeHelper(leftArr, rightArr);
        }

        // copying first half of array
        for (int i = 0; i < mid; i++){
            leftArr[i] = list[i];
        }

        // copying second half of array
        int placeHolder = 0;
        for (int i = mid; i < list.length; i++){
            if (placeHolder < rightArr.length) {
                rightArr[placeHolder] = list[i];
                placeHolder++;
            }
        }

        mergeSort(leftArr);
        mergeSort(rightArr);
    }

    public static int[] mergeHelper(int[] leftArr, int[] rightArr){

        int leftIndex = 0;
        int rightIndex = 0;
        int sortedArrayIndex = 0;
        int[] newList = new int[leftArr.length + rightArr.length];

        while (leftIndex < leftArr.length || rightIndex < rightArr.length){
            if (leftIndex < leftArr.length && rightIndex < rightArr.length){
                if(leftArr[leftIndex] > rightArr[rightIndex]){
                    newList[sortedArrayIndex] = rightArr[rightIndex];
                    rightIndex++;
                    sortedArrayIndex++;
                }
                else {
                    newList[sortedArrayIndex] = leftArr[leftIndex];
                    leftIndex++;
                    sortedArrayIndex++;
                }
            }

            else if (leftIndex < leftArr.length && rightIndex == rightArr.length){
                newList[sortedArrayIndex] = leftArr[leftIndex];
                leftIndex++;
                sortedArrayIndex++;
            }

            else if (rightIndex < rightArr.length && leftIndex == leftArr.length){
                newList[sortedArrayIndex] = rightArr[rightIndex];
                rightIndex++;
                sortedArrayIndex++;
            }
        }
        return newList;
    }

    public static void populateArray(int[] list){
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
            list[i] = (int) ((Math.random() * 100));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        int [] list = new int [10];
        populateArray(list);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list));
        mergeSort(list);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list));


        //proof that mergeHelper() works
        //      int[] left =  {1,3,5,7,9};
        //      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(left));
        //      int[] right = {0,2,4,6,8};
        //      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(right));
        //      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mergeHelper(left,right)));

}
}
```

Comment: You should compare your code to the one on Geek Viewpoint: http://www.geekviewpoint.com/java/sorting/mergesort. Also you should show the error trace.

Answer (score 2):

Your rightArr length determination is not good. Correction:

`rightArr = new int [list.length - mid];`

Answer (score 0):

```
## This is a way to use merge sort in c#, with recursion. ##



 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> list = new List<int>();
        int m = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            int p = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            list.Add(p);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", MergeSort(list)));
    }
    static List<int> MergeSort(List<int> array)
    {
        List<int> output = new List<int>();
        if (array.Count == 1)
        {
            return array;
        }
        if (array.Count == 2)
        {
            if (array[0] > array[1])
            {
                int a = array[1];
                array[1] = array[0];
                array[0] = a;
                return array;
            }
            else
            {
                return array;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            List<int> firstList = new List<int>();
            List<int> secondList = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Count / 2; i++)
            {   
                firstList.Add(array[i]);
                secondList.Add(array[i + array.Count / 2]);   
            }
            if (array.Count % 2 != 0)
            {
                secondList.Add(array[array.Count - 1]);
            }
            firstList = MergeSort(firstList);
            secondList = MergeSort(secondList);
            int k = 0;
            int j = 0;
            int size = firstList.Count + secondList.Count;
            int markerFirst = firstList.Count;
            int markerSecond = secondList.Count;

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                if (k == markerFirst)
                {
                    output.Add(secondList[j]);
                    j++;
                    continue;
                }
                if (j == markerSecond)
                {
                    output.Add(firstList[k]);
                    k++;
                    continue;
                }
                if (firstList[k] < secondList[j])
                {
                    output.Add(firstList[k]);
                    k++;
                }
                else
                {
                    output.Add(secondList[j]);
                    j++;
                }
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a some problems:

1) There isn't a condition to stop the recursive like this code below in "mergeSort" method.You receive stackoverflows because your code is in a infinite loop. Add this code at the first line of "mergeSort" method.

```
if(list.length <= 1) 
    return;
```

2) Fix the "rightArr" size... with this 2 corrections your code run, but not sort.

```
int[] rightArr = new int [list.length - mid];

//        if (mid % 2 == 0) {
//            rightArr = new int[mid];
//        } else {
//            rightArr = new int[mid + 1];
//        }
```

Follows the code in an easier way...

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MergeSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] itens = {2,6,4,9,1,3,8,7,0};

        Integer[] tmp = new Integer[itens.length];
        int left = 0;
        int right = itens.length - 1;

        mergeSort(itens, tmp, left, right);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(itens));
    }

    private static void mergeSort(Integer[] itens, Integer[] tmpArray, int left, int right) {

        if(itens == null || itens.length == 0 || left >= right){
            return;
        }

        int midle = (left + right) / 2;

        mergeSort(itens, tmpArray, left, midle);
        mergeSort(itens, tmpArray, midle + 1, right);

        merge(itens, tmpArray, left, midle + 1, right);
    }

    private static void merge(Integer[] itens, Integer[] tmpArray, int left, int right, int rightEnd) {
        int leftEnd = right - 1;
        int tmpIndex = left;

        while (left <= leftEnd && right <= rightEnd){
            if (itens[left] < itens[right] ){
                tmpArray[tmpIndex++] = itens[left++];
            } else {
                tmpArray[tmpIndex++] = itens[right++];
            }
        }

        while (left <= leftEnd) { // Copy rest of LEFT half
            tmpArray[tmpIndex++] = itens[left++];
        }
        while (right <= rightEnd) { // Copy rest of RIGHT half
            tmpArray[tmpIndex++] = itens[right++];
        }
        while(rightEnd >= 0){ // Copy TEMP back
            itens[rightEnd] = tmpArray[rightEnd--];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please describe what you have done to solve the questioner's problem; as it stands, new code with no explanation doesn't really help anyone learn.

Comment: The code has a lot of problems: 1) there is no condition to stop the recursive like "IF(list.length <= 0) return;"